# Hibernate HQL inner join subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I got the following SQL which I wanted to transform into valid HQL. The issue with this is, that its not permitted to join on a sub-query per the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries). Even though these are old docs (v3.3) this section still seems to still hold in hibernate 5.3.

```
SELECT f.date,
    f.name,
    SUM(f.seats) 
FROM Foo f 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT fl.date,
                        fl.start + fl.end AS code 
                    FROM Foo fl 
                    WHERE fl.date >= (SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                                            FROM Bar) 
                        AND fl.name = :name) fl 
        ON f.start + f.end = code 
        AND f.date = fl.date 
WHERE f.date >= (   SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                        FROM Bar)   
GROUP BY f.date,
    f.name 
ORDER BY f.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

I came up with this HQL:

```
SELECT NEW com.company.project.model.FooRepresentation( f.fooId.date,
    f.fooId.name,
    SUM(f.seats)) 
FROM Foo f 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT fl.fooId.date,
                        fl.fooId.start + fl.fooId.end AS code 
                    FROM Foo fl 
                    WHERE fl.fooId.date >= (SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                                            FROM FooConfig) 
                        AND fl.fooId.name = :name) fl 
        ON f.fooId.start + f.fooId.end = code 
        AND f.fooId.date = fl.fooId.date 
WHERE f.fooId.date >= ( SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                        FROM FooConfig) 
GROUP BY f.fooId.date,
    f.fooId.name 
ORDER BY f.fooId.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

Trying to execute this HQL query, results in this exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 169
```

which hints to the `(` at `INNER JOIN (SELECT`.

**Is there a way to join on sub-queries within HQL? If not, what would be the best way to achieve the same results as the SQL with HQL?**

---

I am not that good with converting the `inner join on <sub-query>` to an actual `where` clause where the sub-query is permitted

Comment: What's the reason why you want to do this rather than sticking to SQL?

Comment: Mostly the convenience of having the result translated to a non `@Entity` class (`NEW com.company.project.model.FooRepresentation()`)

Comment: Oh, the `NEW com.company.project.model.FooRepresentation` syntax? But I mean, that's one line of code to map from the `Object[]` to a constructor call, compared to rewriting it all :) Anyway - I'm not sure this will be an easy rewrite...

Comment: Without the inconvenience that joins on subqueries are not allowed, this wouldn't actually be that hard to convert. Its basically only replacing the column names. So you would suggest that I use a native query and map it on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your SQL query can be rewritten to this:

```sql
SELECT f.date, f.name, SUM(f.seats) 
FROM Foo f 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Foo f1
  WHERE f.start + f.end = f1.start + f1.end
  AND f.date = f1.date
  AND f1.date >= (SELECT MAX(earliestDate) FROM Bar)
  AND f1.name = :name  
)
AND f.date >= (SELECT MAX(earliestDate) FROM Bar)
GROUP BY f.date, f.name
ORDER BY f.date ASC, SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

This should be simpler to translate to HQL, and it might even be more correct, because your original query seems to create an unwanted cartesian product between the self joined rows.

There's probably an even better way to query this in SQL, without self joining the Foo table, using a single pass through the table. But I'd need to know more about your real world use-case for that, and what RDBMS you're using.

Comment: This should really be simpler to translate to HQL. So far the results are the same, while my query seems to be a bit faster (around 5-10 milliseconds, though my benchmarking skills are low). I am using MSSQL 2017. I need to fetch for each date every name where start+end are in start+end for a specific name. The `sum(f.seats)` is only used for ordering (I hope this is understandable). For now I used a `ResultTransformer`, but might switch back and use your query

Comment: The way you describe this your query was definitely wrong, but you might not have noticed, because the error might have manifested only in subtly wrong ordering in edge cases. In order to speed things up, you could create a [computed column `start_plus_end`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) on `start + end`, and add an index on `(date, name, start_plus_end)`

Comment: Well, you inner joined instead of semi joined... :) Inner joins create cartesian products, which is what they're designed to do. But you didn't want that cartesian product. I have blogged about these things a few times, e.g. https://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/13/semi-join-and-anti-join-should-have-its-own-syntax-in-sql/, https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/12/a-probably-incomplete-comprehensive-guide-to-the-many-different-ways-to-join-tables-in-sql/. In short, when inner joining, you repeat rows from the `f` table several times for matching rows in the `f1` table. This is slow and produces wrong results.

Comment: ... it might be faster in specific cases, but it's definitely slow in many others. The reason why your solution might've been faster is because I omitted the unnecessary `f.date >= (SELECT ...)` filter on the outer query. It seems that SQL Server isn't able to infer this on its own. I'll edit my answer and re-add that filter.

Comment: Thanks for all the sources. I converted the query to HQL and currently test it to check if the results match up.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @LukasEder's answer, I created this HQL:

```
SELECT NEW com.company.project.model.FooRepresentation( f.fooId.date,
    f.fooId.name,
    SUM(f.seats) ) 
FROM Foo f 
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                FROM Foo f1 
                WHERE f.fooId.start + f.fooId.end = f1.fooId.start + f1.fooId.end 
                    AND f.fooId.date = f1.fooId.date 
                    AND f1.fooId.date >= (  SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                                            FROM FooConfig) 
                    AND f1.fooId.name = :name ) 
    AND f.fooId.date >= (   SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                            FROM FooConfig) 
GROUP BY f.fooId.date,
    f.fooId.name 
ORDER BY f.fooId.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

Previously I was running this native SQL query with a `ResultTransformer`:

```
SELECT f.date,
    f.name,
    SUM(f.seats) 
FROM Foo f 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT fl.date,
                        fl.start + fl.end AS code 
                    FROM Foo fl 
                    WHERE fl.date >= (  SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                                        FROM FooConfig) 
                        AND fl.name = :name) fl 
        ON f.start + f.end = code 
        AND f.date = fl.date 
WHERE f.date >= (   SELECT MAX(earliestDate) 
                    FROM FooConfig) 
GROUP BY f.date,
    f.name 
ORDER BY f.date ASC,
    SUM(f.seats) DESC
```

there are actually slight differences with the results between the two queries, but those are not consistent. With consistent I mean in this case, that its not for every possible `date` that the results differ, just for some. Also for the provided parameter `:name`, the results are consistent. I will evaluate more on which results are more fitting, but I wouldn't be surprised if the new ones are correct.